# Use of uninitialized value $_ in hash element

Tags: perl, hash, compilation, syntax-error, element

This is regarding a warning message I received when running a Perl script.

I understand why I'm receiving this warning: probably because `$element` is undefined when being called but I don't see it.

```
for ( my $element->{$_}; @previous_company_names; ) {
    map { $element => $previous_company_names->{$_} }
            0 .. $previous_company_names;
```

The result is this message

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in hash element
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code snippet. You're using `$_` incorrectly I think, and to give a correct example it'd be useful to understand what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Please don't delete your posts like that. This site works by allowing others to refer back to, and search other questions. If the original question is removed, so too is the context.

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost - for a new programmer, absolutely the most important thing you must do, is `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. You've got `my` in there, which suggests you might be, but it pays to re-iterate it.

`$_` is a special variable, called the implicit variable. It doesn't really make sense to use it in the way you're doing like that, in a for loop. Take a look at [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) for some more detail.

Indeed, I'd suggest steering clear of `map` entirely until you really grok it, because it's a good way to confuse yourself.

With a `for` (or `foreach`) loop you can either:

```
for my $thing ( @list_of_things ) {
    print $thing;
 }
```

Or you can do:

```
for ( @list_of_things ) {
   print $_;
}
```

`$_` is set implicitly by each iteration of the second loop, which can be quite useful because lots of things default to using it.

E.g.

```
for ( @list_of_things ) {
   chomp; 
   s/ /_/g;
   print;
}
```

When it comes to [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) - map is a clever little function, that lets you evaluate a code block for each element in a list. Personally - I still get confused by it, and tend to stick with `for` or `foreach` loops instead, most of the time.

But what you're doing with it, isn't really going to work - `map` *makes* a hash.

So something like:

```
use Data::Dumper; 
my %things = map { $_ => 1 } 1..5; 
print Dumper \%things;
```

This creates the hash 'things':

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 1,
          '3' => 1,
          '5' => 1,
          '4' => 1,
          '2' => 1
        };
```

Again, `$_` is used inside, because it's the magic variable - it's set to 'whatever was in the second bit' (e.g 1,2,3,4,5) each loop, and then the block is evaluated.

So your [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) expression doesn't really make a lot of sense, because you don't have `$element` defined... and even if you did, you'd repeatedly overwrite it.

I would also note - `$previous_company_names` would need to be numeric, and is in NO way related to `@previous_company_names`. You might be meaning to use `$#previous_company_names` which is the last element index.